# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode 10.0 and Ionic 3

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

I updated my Xcode to version 10.0 and now my ionic project don't build more.

I changed my File->Project Settings->Build System to Legacy to work with onesignal (onsesignal recomendation), but in Legacy build system i got the same error:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Note: Before updating the Xcode there was no error.

I'm using Ionic 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to definitively answer this question, but you can try removing files highlighted in red in your project navigator. I had to remove "libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib" when I updated to XCode 10 for some reason.

Comment: You removed libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib from reference or file? What information more you need?

Comment: From reference. It wasn't causing issues in XCode 9, but it was in XCode 10. The rest of that error message should tell you what's causing the clang error.

Comment: What file got the reference? i searched in my ios folder (under /platforms) and don't find it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you look through your project navigator, do you see any files highlighted in red?

Comment: ld: library not found for -lPods-MyApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: aha, I bet that file is referenced, but the location has moved. XCode 9 was less finicky about having abandoned files laying around. Look (in every folder) for that file highlighted in red, and remove it (and re-add if necessary)

Comment: this file not exist.it would be in the compile ipa.